# Ruby code what does "&:" do here

Tags: ruby

```
def reverse_words(s)
    s.split.map(&:reverse).join(' ')
end
```

This code reverses each word in a sentence.  But I do not understand "&:" in the code.  Can someone explain that to me?

Comment: *Definitely* not Python.  That's Ruby.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: SymbolHound is your friend for hard to Google things like this: http://symbolhound.com/?q=ruby+%26%3A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` means that `reverse` is referencing a function, not a block.

This method assumes that the caller will pass it a String object.

1. First the method [#split](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#split-method)s the *string* on whitespaces into an array (if the string has no whitespaces it creates an array with the string as the only element)
2. Calls the [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#map-method) method on the new array and passes it a reference to the [String#reverse](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#reverse-method) method.

The `&` tells the map method that the input is a reference to a method and not a standard block

Comment: This has nothing to do with method references. A method reference would be something like `each(&method(:puts))`. Also, this has nothing to do with `map`. `map` doesn't know whether you pass a block directly or via the unary prefix ampersand operator.

Answer (score 1):

`map` expects a code block that takes one argument. What you would normally do is to call reverse on that argument:

```
map {|elt| elt.reverse }
```

With the `&` syntax you can shorten this to

```
map(&:reverse)
```

The colon is there to make a symbol out of the name `reverse`.