# Ruby: How to convert an array of numbers into characters using .chr method?

Tags: ruby

I'm a ruby beginner and would like some help!

Let's say we have the following array:

```
codes = [65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 84]
```

What ruby code do we have to call, to change this array into `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]`?

I want to use the chr method

Comment: `codes.map(&:chr)`

Comment: [so] is not a write-my-code-for-me-service. (Those *do* exist, they are called "programmers", and you can hire them for a fee.) You need to show what you have tried, what is and isn't working. Please, provide a [mcve], a specification of what your desired behavior is (including any and all edge cases, e.g. what should happen with an empty array, what should happen with a number that is outside the range of Unicode code points, etc.), and give example inputs and desired outputs demonstrating both normal operation and edge cases. Also, take the [tour] and read the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You want [Array#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-map).

```
[65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 84].map { |number| number.chr }
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "T"]
```

And it's more idiomatic to use [Symbol#to_proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby):

```
[65, 66, 67, 68, 70, 84].map(&:chr)
=> ["A", "B", "C", "D", "F", "T"]
```

Comment: of note, [Symbol#to_proc](https://github.com/JuanitoFatas/fast-ruby/blob/master/code/proc-and-block/block-vs-to_proc.rb) is faster.