# What this 'map' function does in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone explain this code:

```
dates = (from_date..to_date).map(&:to_s)
```

So that it helps me to do the project!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Why you don't try it by yourself in console, then you will get answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally map creates a new array containing the values returned by the block. What you are doing here is: defined two function `from_date` & `to_date` and which return(I assume) two dates and then converting it to array of date range from `from_date` to `to_date`

```
2.0.0-p648 :010 > date = Date.today.prev_day
 => #<Date: 2017-08-09 ((2457975j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)> 
2.0.0-p648 :011 > (date..Date.today).map(&:to_s)
 => ["2017-08-09", "2017-08-10"] 
2.0.0-p648 :012 >
```

Comment: from_data/to_date could also be variables instead of methods.

Comment: yes they can be.