# Ruby Hash: type casting

Tags: ruby, hash, each, enumerate

I’m trying to get a better grasp on writing in Ruby and working with Hash tables and their values.

*1.* Say you have a hash:

```
‘FOO’= {‘baz’ => [1,2,3,4,5]}
```

Goal: convert each value into a string in the ‘Ruby’ way.

I’ve come across multiple examples of using `.each` eg.

```
FOO.each = { |k,v| FOO[k] = v.to_s }
```

However this renders an array encapsulated in a string. Eg. `"[1,2,3,4,5]"` where it should be `["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]`.

*2.* When type casting is performed on a Hash that’s holds an array of values, is the result a new array? Or simply a change in type of value (eg. 1 becomes “1” when `.to_s` is applied (say the value was placed through a `each` enumerator like above).

An explanation is greatly appreciated. New to Ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the each block, `k` and `v` are the key value pair. In your case, `'baz'` is key and `[1,2,3,4,5]` is value. Since you're doing `v.to_s`, it converts the whole array to string and not the individual values.

You can do something like this to achieve what you want.

```
foo = { 'baz' => [1,2,3,4,5] }
foo.each { |k, v| foo[k] = v.map(&:to_s) }
```

Comment: Of course, this will fail when `v` is _not_ an array. :shrug: But let this be OP's homework :)

Comment: 1. Does the `map` portion iterate over each value and replace the original value types? 2. `&:s` ? Shortcut for applying string to each value?

Comment: @thesayhey Yes map loops over each element of array and creates a new array containing the values returned by the block.

Comment: @thesayhey You can go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby) to understand `&:`. It's explained well and is one of the thing you'll see a lot in ruby.

Comment: Much appreciated. Will spend some time. Def trying to nail down fundamentals and Ruby best practice. Thanks Anurag!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Hash#transform_values`:

```
foo = { 'baz' => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }                                     
foo.transform_values { |v| v.map(&:to_s) } #=> {"baz"=>["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]}
```