# Get value of all constants defined in a module

Tags: ruby

I want to get the values of all the constants defined in a module:

```
module Letters
  A = 'apple'.freeze
  B = 'boy'.freeze
end
```

`constants` gave me the name of the constants:

```
Letters.constants(false)
#=> [:A, :B]
```

How do I get an array of their values, i.e. `["apple", "boy"]`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. But why don't you want to use symbols?

Comment: instead of `each`, use `map` here. That's what it's for.

Comment: We are using third party library that requires to use strings.

Comment: But I am not sure what does &: doing here ?

Comment: Long story :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: Just noticed and realised that it gives [:A, :B] and not [:a,:b] , I mean its name of constant and not its value. I need value

Comment: `Letters.constants(false).map &Letters.method(:const_get)`.

Comment: @stefan We are using Kwalify library to validate YAML file. One o the keys can take list of String values as Kwalify has type str for string. We are loading these values from a module of constants defined in some class.

Comment: @mudasobwa that's going to be a steep learning curve for the OP ;-)

Comment: @mudasobwa . **awesome**.  Exactly what I required, Could you give me references to read to understand its real meaning.

Comment: @Stefan Yes you are right , I realised it later since I used same name of constants and its values . I have modified it now.

Comment: Do you want the values in a specific order?

Comment: @Stefan No, order is not importan

Answer (score 16):

In order to do this use map

```
Letters.constants(false).map &Letters.method(:const_get)
```

this will return `["a","b"]`

Second way :

```
Letters.constants(false).map { |c| Letters.const_get c }
```

Thanks @mudasobwa and Sagar Pandya for their answer.

Comment: Some may prefer `Letters.constants(false).map { |c| Letters.const_get c }`

Comment: You edited your answer to replace what you had initially with @mudasobwa's comment (*verbatim!*). Considering that mudsie chose not to submit an answer, there's nothing wrong with that (it's a good answer, so we need to see it), but don't you think you should have attributed it to him?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Absolutely !