# How does Ampersand pass arguments into #to_proc as "obj"? —receiving_method(&:method)

Tags: ruby, proc

receiver_method(&:method) functionality seems clear enough, yet I find a gap in the explanations* about the **assignment to** '**obj**' as in—

```
class Symbol
  def to_proc #<parameter notably absent>
    Proc.new { |obj, *args|
      obj.send (self, *args)
    }
  end
end
```

How does this assign the receiver method's object/passed argument as 'obj'?

---

*
[What does map(&:name) mean in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby)

*
https://www.skorks.com/2013/04/ruby-ampersand-parameter-demystified/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Ampersand pass arguments into `#to_proc` as `“obj”`? — `receiving_method(&:method)`

Ampersand does not pass anything anywhere. Ampersand converts the argument to a `proc` instance, implicitly calling `to_proc` on it. And passes the result as a block to the caller.

Let’s stick with the example:

```
%w[42 foo].map(&:to_i)
#⇒ [42, 0]
```

What’s going on here?

• `to_i` is being converted to `proc` as you shown in the OP

```
#                            ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓
proc { |obj, *args| obj.send(:to_i, *args) }
```

• we pass this `proc` to the caller (without lose of generality, I’d write it with block syntax for the sake of clarity

```
%w[42 foo].map do |obj, *args|
  obj.send(:to_i, *args)
end
```

• *NB!* `*args` is off-side here, since `map` passes the single argument to the block:

```
%w[42 foo].map do |obj|
  obj.send(:to_i)
end
```

That would map:

```
'42' → '42'.send(:to_i) ≡ '42'.to_i → 42,
'foo' → 'foo'.send(:to_i) ≡ 'foo'.to_i → 0,
```

yielding:

```
#⇒ [42, 0]
```

Comment: the receiver method* actually calls the proc (not yields-to), I gather?

the question I first-linked, says 'uses as the method's block'

*a specific type of method known as a caller?

Comment: Yield to the block is literally the same as calling a proc.