# Chaining method blocks (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

Considering the following code:

```rb
    lines = Array.new() 
    File.foreach('file.csv').with_index do |line, line_num|                 
      lines.push(line.split(" ")) if line_num > 0                                 
    end                                                                                  

    indices = lines.map { |el| el.last }                                          
    duplicates = indices.select{ |e| indices.count(e) > 2 }.uniq
```

Example CSV file looks like this for all who wonder:

```
# Generated by tool XYZ
a b c 1
d e f 2
g h i 1
j k l 4
m n o 5
p q r 2
s t u 2
v w x 1
y z 0 5
```

Is it possible to chain these two methods blocks (last two lines of code) together?

Comment: Seems like your file contains a header line and space separated values. It might be worth taking a look at Ruby's [CSV](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class.

Comment: Yes, this might be a good idea as well. However my file consists out of one comment string ("# Generated by tool XYZ") in the first line (No real CSV header thus). Which I can simply skip with the iterator above. Correct?

Comment: Sure, although `File.foreach('file.csv').drop(1)` might be cleaner in that case.

Comment: Stefan: Fabulous. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to have a intermediate variable and want to do it in a single line, you can write something like this:

```
duplicates = lines.group_by(&:last).select{|k, v| v.count > 2}.keys
```

For some people, this might hinder readability though! Just depends on your taste.

Comment: How do you call the &:last  syntax? It's not a method reference but a shorthand notation. Pretzel colon? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby

Comment: So, also this should be valid: duplicates = lines.group_by {|e| e.last}.select{|k, v| v.count > 2}.keys if understood the &:method syntax correctly which convert's basically a proc to a block.

Answer (score 1):

`O(N)` solution (single pass) would look like:

```
lines.each_with_object([[], []]) do |el, (result, temp)|
  (temp.delete(el) ? result : temp) << el
end.first
```

Here we use an intermediate

---

Also, you always might use [`Object#tap`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
duplicates =
  lines.map(&:last).tap do |indices|
    indices.select { |e| indices.count(e) > 2 }.uniq
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

Let's apply your code to an example.

```
str =<<-END
Now is the
time for all
people who are
known to all
of us as the
best coders are
expected to
lead all
those who are
less experienced
to greatness
END
```

```
FName = 'temp'
File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 146
```

**Your code**

```
lines = Array.new() 
File.foreach(FName).with_index do |line, line_num|                 
  lines.push(line.split(" ")) if line_num > 0                                 
end                                                                                  
lines
  #=> [["time", "for", "all"], ["people", "who", "are"], ["known", "to", "all"],
  #    ["of", "us", "as", "the"], ["best", "coders", "are"], ["expected", "to"],
  #    ["lead", "all"], ["those", "who", "are"], ["less", "experienced"],
  #    ["to", "greatness"]] 
indices = lines.map { |el| el.last }                                          
  #=> ["all", "are", "all", "the", "are", "to", "all", "are", "experienced", "greatness"] 
duplicates = indices.select { |e| indices.count(e) > 2 }
  #=> ["all", "are", "all", "are", "all", "are"] 
duplicates.uniq
  #=> ["all", "are"]
```

The object is seen to return an array of all words that appear as the last word of a line (other than the first line) more than twice.

**More Ruby-like and more efficient code**

We can do that more concisely and efficiently by making a single pass through the file:

```
first_line = true
h = Hash.new(0)
File.foreach(FName) do |line|
  if first_line
    first_line = false
  else
    h[line[/\S+(?=\n)/]] += 1
  end
end
h.select { |_,count| count > 2 }.keys
  #=> ["all", "are"]
```

**Steps performed**

The steps are as follows.

```
first_line = true
h = Hash.new(0)
File.foreach(FName) do |line|
  if first_line
    first_line = false
  else
    h[line[/\S+(?=\n)/]] += 1
  end
end
h #=> {"all"=>3, "are"=>3, "the"=>1, "to"=>1, "experienced"=>1, "greatness"=>1}
g = h.select { |_,count| count > 2 }
  #=> {"all"=>3, "are"=>3} 
g.keys
  #=> ["all", "are"]
```

**Use of [Enumerator#each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerator.html)**

Rather than defining the hash before `File.foreach(..)` is executed, its customary to use the method `Enumerator#each_object`, which allows us to chain the hash that is constructed to that statements that follow:

```
first_line = true
File.foreach(FName).with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |line, h|
  if first_line
    first_line = false
  else
    h[line[/\S+(?=\n)/]] += 1
  end
end.select { |_,count| count > 2 }.keys
  #=> ["all", "are"]
```

**Use of a *counting hash***

I define the hash as follows.

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Hash.html#method-c-new) that defines a *default value* equal to `new`s argument. If `h = Hash.new(0)` and `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, zero.  Ruby's parser expands the expression `h[k] += 1` to:

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` does not have a key `k`, the expression becomes

```
h[k] = 0 + 1
```

Note that `h[k] = h[k] + 1` is shorthand for:

```
h.[]=(k, h.[](k) + 1)
```

It is the method `Hash#[]` that defaults to zero, not the method `Hash#[]=`.

**Using a regular expression to extract the last word of each line**

One of the lines is

```
str = "known to all\n"
```

We can use the regular expression `r = /\S+(?=\n)/` to extract the last word:

```
str[r] #=> "all"
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more (`+`) characters that are not whitespace characters (`\S`), immediately followed by a newline character. `(?=\n)` is a *positive lookahead*. `"\n"` must be matched by it is not part of the match returned.

Comment: Great examples. Thanks.