# creating my own Enumerable method my_none? for Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have created my own `Enumerable` method `my_none?`. It gives me lint error:

> Convert `if` nested inside `else` to `elsif`.

Also two of the test cases are not working. Can anyone help me to resolve these issues?

```
module Enumerable
  def my_each
    i = 0
    while i < size
      yield self[i]
      i += 1
    end
  end

  def my_none?
    my_each do |item|
      if block_given?
        return false if yield item
       else
         return false if item
      end
    end
    true
  end
end
```

```
%w{ant bear cat}.my_none? { |word| word.length == 5 } #=> true
%w{ant bear cat}.my_none? { |word| word.length >= 4 } #=> false
```

```
[].my_none?                                           #=> true
[nil].my_none?                                        #=> true
[nil, false].my_none?                                 #=> true
[nil, false, true].my_none?                           #=> false
```

The below two test cases are not working:

```
%w{ant bear cat}.my_none?(/d/)                        #=> true > gives me wrong no of argument given 1 expected 0
[1, 3.14, 42].my_none?(Float)                         #=> false > gives me wrong number of argument
```

Comment: How about lint errors C: Style/IfInsideElse: Convert `if` nested inside `else` to `elsif`.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`my_none?` method, as you defined it, does not accept any arguments. It can only accept block.

I think you meant:

```
%w{ant bear cat}.my_none?{|e| e =~ /d/ }
[1, 3.14, 42].my_none?(&:to_f)
```

`&:to_f` is a way to create a [Proc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Proc.html) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217088/what-does-mapname-mean-in-ruby) for more info.

To get rid of the lint errors you can change `my_none?` implementation to:

```
def my_none?
  my_each do |item|
    return false if block_given? && yield(item) || !block_given? && item
  end
  true
end
```